# What is this slug-like thing I found in my bed?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

what is this thing I found in my bed? Squishy like a slug, mildly freaked out, help? I'm in Scotland Edinburgh 
[image]

Comment: It appears to be upside down.. can you flip the creature and post another picture of it? That would help quite a bit. Thanks.

Comment: it looks like your slug-like thing could be a slug! it might av gotten in stuck to your clothes (or if you have a pet, stuck to that). but a better picture would be helpful.

Comment: It might be a "bed slug".